# Nodejs Event error Express

Tags: node.js, express

i have this code in express.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
var app = express();

var optionsSB = {
     host: 'domain.com',
     path: '/wp-content/themes/domain/includes/ajax/get_properties.php'
};

var optionsLV = {
    host: 'apiproperties.local',
    path: '/properties/storeSB',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

https.get(optionsSB, function (https_res) {
    var dataSB = "";
    https_res.on("data", function (chunkSB) {
       dataSB += chunkSB;
    });
    https_res.on("end", function () {
        http.request(optionsLV, function(http_res){
            var dataVL = "";
            http_res.on("data", function (chunkVL) {
                dataVL += chunkVL;
            });
            http_res.on("end", function () {
                console.log(dataVL);
            });
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {});
```

I get this error

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

I already try some things but i dont know what is the problem, regards.
I follow some instruction from a tutorials and all works fine but that error i dont understand.

Comment: what's this have to do with laravel or jquery?

Comment: sorry i put for default, because my code original is jquery and i use laravel, i am converting to express xD

Answer (score 0):

It will throw like this when you are getting an error in setting up the request with your `https.get()`, but you don't have any error handler to capture the error.  You can supply an error handler:

```
https.get(...).on('error', function(err) {
    // error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

It appears that the specific error is ECONNREFUSED.  It could be that the destination is not accepting your https connection or it could be that it doesn't like the way you were passing the options.  Since all you have is a host and path, you can also just use the URL:

```
https.get("https://somedomain.com//wp-content/themes/domain/includes/ajax/get_properties.php", ...);
```

Comment: I already modify my entire code, and now the problem is other, i make new question, thanks.

Comment: @AlanCordova - What new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235260/node-js-access-to-api-laravel

Comment: @AlanCordova - For my help, you need to handle this question first.  Does this provide an answer to what you previously asked?  Questions here should not be just left to rot.  I went to the trouble of answering what you posted.  I'd like feedback on whether this was an appropriate answer or not.