# Node Js access to api laravel

Tags: node.js

Hi i already have one api in laravel, but i need access with express node js.

This is my funcition

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
    _token: 'LhTsymoueRtcWtjP69MD1KEbDyGl0NGuewWOieER',
    propertiesString: properties
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'apiproperties.local',
    port: 80,
    path: '/properties/storeSB',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
    /*headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }*/
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

This give me error Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68 because i dont send _token, but i dont know how send token in nodejs i not have views in nodejs because i not want to use i not need it, so how send token in my post request without call for form in one view? regards

Comment: Where does the PHP code expect the token to be?  As a custom header?  In the query string?  In the POST body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude your api written in `Laravel` from CSRF Protection check middleware by default `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware is applied to route group `web` so here you are having two options :-

1. **Create a new middleware group named `api`**
   *code snippet for creating a middleware*
   **routes.php**

   `Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1','middleware' => ['api']], function () {
       Route::get('/hotel/list',[
           'uses' => 'YourController@function'
       ]);
   });`

   **VerifyCsrfToken.php**

   `protected $except = [
       'api/v1/*',
   ];`
2. **Directly exclude routes for CSRF check**
   In `VerifyCsrfToken.php` add all api's url which you want to ignore for CSRF check

   `class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
   {
       /**
        * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $except = [
           'url_regex'
       ];
   }`

First method is more suggested as for all future new routes addition would work out we just need to add that route under this middleware group.

Let me know in comments if it worked out or if have any query.

Comment: Sorry i dont answer, yes i exclude the routes for the verify, thanks xD